# Trying to write a basic C Program in XCode, but i keep getting an error saying 'Expected expression'

Tags: c, xcode, function, compiler-errors, switch-statement

So the program's meant to read in a water temp, in kelvin, convert it to Celsius and Fahrenheit, then display whichever of those two is requested, as well as the state.

But for whatever reason, when ever I try and call to the `C` or the `F`, it fails to build because it wants something before the int in these two lines of code.

```
case 'c': 
case 'C': 
          ConvertnumberC(int N); 
          CheckState(int N); 
          break;

case 'f': 
case 'F': 
          ConvertnumberF(int N); 
          CheckState(int N); 
          break;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, change

```
 ConvertnumberC(int N);
```

to

```
ConvertnumberC(N);
```

because, while calling the function, you don't need to specify the data type.

Simmilarly, you've to correct all the occurrences.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me the reason behind the downvote so that I can corrct myself? Thank you. :-)

Comment: @Mouse thanks. Can you tell me why it _did not work_? What is the error now? Undefined `N`?

Comment: No, it builds now, but it's no longer reading in the initial temp, it just reads n as 0

Comment: @Mouse How do you define and set the value of `N` in code?

Comment: Just a standard printf, scanf combo.
int readNumber()
{
int N;
printf("Please input intital Kelvin temp\n");
scanf("%d%*c", &N);
return(N);
}

Comment: @Mouse I think problem is elsewhere. Can you share the full code through http://ideone.com so that I can have a look at it?

Comment: Sure, here it is ideone.com/x69VqG @SouravGhosh